# Simple Adapter filtering give null ponter exception

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a list view using simple adapter. Here is my code and xml

```
list_main2.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:orientation="horizontal"  
android:paddingTop="3dip"  
android:paddingBottom="3dip"  
> 
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="2dip"/>

    <LinearLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="2dip"
    > 

<LinearLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="2dip"
    android:weightSum="3.0"
    > 
    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/caption1"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_marginRight="1dip"   
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:lines="1"
        /> 
        <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/caption2"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_marginRight="1dip"   
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:lines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="2.0"
        /> 
        <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/caption3"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_marginRight="1dip"   
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:lines="1"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        /> 
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>     
</LinearLayout>
```

and my code to listview

```
listView = getListView();
        View v1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tabhost, null);
        listView.addHeaderView(v1);

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, records_of_module, R.layout.list_main2, dispCols, 
                new int[] { R.id.icon,R.id.caption1,R.id.caption2,R.id.caption3,
                R.id.caption4,R.id.caption5,R.id.caption6 });

        setListAdapter(adapter);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

and filtering by

```
adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I dont kw from getting exception. My stack trace look like this

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:93)
at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:689)
at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AdapterView.java:812)
at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyInvalidated(DataSetObservable.java:43)
at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(BaseAdapter.java:54)
at android.widget.SimpleAdapter$SimpleFilter.publishResults(SimpleAdapter.java:383)
```

Please help me by some tips

thanks in advance
Joe

Comment: Post the code where getCount() method is.

Comment: getCount() is a public method of the SimpleAdapter class.  I doubt that Joe's problem is there, since he didn't write that code :)

Answer (score 0):

It might not solve everything, but the constructor for your SimpleAdapter references fields that are not in your xml file.  Your layout contains icon as well as caption1, caption2, and caption3, but not caption4, caption5, or caption6.

According to the [documentation for SimpleAdapters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) the xml resource that you provide must contain at least all of the items that you specify in the last field of the constructor.

Comment: sorry i didnt put complete xml. The 'list_main2.xml' contains one more linear layout and include caption4, caption5 and caption6. Can you figure out any other issue..? thanks u.

Comment: Ah, ok then.  Can you show where you have defined records_of_module and dispCols?

Comment: I found the issue. I initialized records_of_module like this 'List<Map<String,?>> records_of_module = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();' . Map contains objects and strings. Map should be  'Map<String, String>' if u use 'adapter.getFilter().filter(s)'. But i made custom SimpleAdapter and caught the exception. Plz correct me, if i am wrong. Thank u all.